# Find all matched string by regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a combined command string like below, and each command length is not fixed, minimum is 22, maximum is 240:

> 5B01CA0F00000241FF0201040F325D5B01CA0F00000241FF0201040F335D6B01FF0000000010FF01FF0000000F6D5B01CA0F00000241FF0201040F345D5B01CA0F00000241FF0201040F355D6B01FF0000000010FF01FF0000000F6D

I want to extract command like 5B....5D or 6B....6D, so the expected result is :

> 5B01CA0F00000241FF0201040F325D
>
> 5B01CA0F00000241FF0201040F335D
>
> 6B01FF0000000010FF01FF0000000F6D
>
> 5B01CA0F00000241FF0201040F345D
>
> 5B01CA0F00000241FF0201040F355D
>
> 6B01FF0000000010FF01FF0000000F6D

I used regex pattern like

`5B[0-9a-fA-F]{22,240}5D`
or
`(?<=5B)([0-9a-fA-F]{22,240})(?=5D)`

Only one matched, can anyone help me for this?

```
string regexPattern = "(?<=5B)([0-9a-fA-F]{22,240})(?=5D)";
string command = txtRegexCmd.Text.Trim();
MatchCollection matchedResults = Regex.Matches(command, regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string matchedCmd = string.Empty;
foreach (Match matchResult in matchedResults)
{
    matchedCmd += matchResult.Value + ",\r\n";
}
MessageBox.Show(matchedCmd);
```

Comment: Yes, if there is no way by regex, I will use string split to implement.

Comment: `Regex.Split(s, @"(?<=[56]D)")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match them using

```
([65])B.*?\1D
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5B65%5D%29B.*%3F%5C1D&i=5B01CA0F00000241FF0201040F325D5B01CA0F00000241FF0201040F335D6B01FF0000000010FF01FF0000000F6D5B01CA0F00000241FF0201040F345D5B01CA0F00000241FF0201040F355D6B01FF0000000010FF01FF0000000F6D) and the Regulex graph:

[image]

The `([65])B.*?\1D` pattern captures into Group 1 a `5` or `6` digit, then matches `B`, then any 0+ chars other than a newline as few as possible up to the first occurrence of the same char as captured in Group 1 followed with `D`.

C# code:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"([65])B.*?\1D")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(x => x.Value)
            .ToList();
```

[image]

If you want to split after each `5D` or `6D`, just use

```
var results = Regex.Split(s, @"(?!$)(?<=[56]D)");
```

Here, `(?!$)(?<=[56]D)` matches  a location that is not the string end and it must be immediately preceded with `5D` or `6D`. See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f!%24%29%28%3f%3c%3d%5b65%5dD%29&i=5B01CA0F00000241FF0201040F325D5B01CA0F00000241FF0201040F335D6B01FF0000000010FF01FF0000000F6D5B01CA0F00000241FF0201040F345D5B01CA0F00000241FF0201040F355D6B01FF0000000010FF01FF0000000F6D).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can split string on characters as suggested by Emma. If you must use regex, you can use lookbehind like this.

**Regex:** `(?<=5D|6D)`

**Explanation:** It will search for zero width after `5D` and `6D`. Then you can add newline character as replacement.

**[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kG3Hfz/1)**

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/3HySxS/1) might help you to separate your string into desired pieces that you wish.

```
(?:5|6)B[0-9a-fA-F]{26,28}(?:5|6)D
```

It would create two left and right boundaries for each desired output.

[image: RegEx]

Comment: Thanks, but each command length is not fixed, minimum is 22, and maximum is 240, this not works if I changed command length